# Problem having ttk.Notebook() tabs centered

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to create a simple GUI in order to solve structures.

The aim is to let the user add tabs to the GUI if he/she wants to start another project even if a tab is already opened.

My main problem right now is that when a tab is created according the following code, it is centered instead of being created from left to right:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Pytures(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        #Title
        main_window.title("Pytures 0.1.1")
        #Geometry initialation
        width = main_window.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = main_window.winfo_screenheight()
        scSize = str(width) + 'x' + str(height)
        main_window.geometry(scSize)

        #Calls the MenuBar function during initialation
        self.MenuBar(main_window)

        #Initialize first blank tab -> Tab1
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.tab_names = {}
        self.tabAttr_names = {}

        self.TabClassCreator()
        self.TabAttributeCreator()

        self.pack()

    def TabClassCreator(self):
        # It creates new tab classes 
        global how_many_tabs
        how_many_tabs = len(self.tab_names)

        if how_many_tabs >= 1:
            self.tab_names[how_many_tabs] = 'Tab'+str(how_many_tabs+1)
            exec('global {0}\nclass {0}(ttk.Frame):\n\tdef __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):\n\t\tsuper().__init__(*args, **kwargs)'.format(self.tab_names[how_many_tabs]))
        else:

            self.tab_names[0] = 'Tab1'

            exec('global {0}\nclass {0}(ttk.Frame):\n\tdef __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):\n\t\tsuper().__init__(*args, **kwargs)'.format(self.tab_names[0]))

        print('Is the class TabN created?')
        print('Class TabN created-> {}'.format(eval(self.tab_names[how_many_tabs])))

    def TabAttributeCreator(self):
        # It creates new tab attributes
        if how_many_tabs >= 1:
            self.tabAttr_names[how_many_tabs] = 'Tab_'+str(how_many_tabs+1)
            exec('self.{0} = {1}(self.notebook)'.format(self.tabAttr_names[how_many_tabs], self.tab_names[how_many_tabs]))
            self.notebook.add(eval('self.{0}'.format(self.tabAttr_names[how_many_tabs])), text=self.tab_names[how_many_tabs])
            self.notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        else:
            self.tabAttr_names[0] = 'Tab_1'
            exec('self.{0} = {1}(self.notebook)'.format(self.tabAttr_names[0], self.tab_names[0]))
            self.notebook.add(eval('self.{0}'.format(self.tabAttr_names[0])), text=self.tab_names[0])
            self.notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
            print('Attribute Tab_N created-> '+str(eval('self.Tab_1')))
        return eval('self.{}'.format(self.tabAttr_names[how_many_tabs]))

    def MenuBar(self, main_window):

        global menubar

        menubar = tk.Menu(main_window)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New (ctrl + n)", command=None)#newTab) #command=create_tab.createTab(tabControl)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open (ctrl + o)", command=None)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save (ctrl + s)", command=None)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=None) #saveAs
        filemenu.add_command(label="Close (ctrl + k)", command=None)#closeTab)

        filemenu.add_separator()

        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=None)

        editmenu.add_separator()

        editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=None)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=None)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=None)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=None)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=None)

        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=None)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=None)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)


        main_window.config(menu=menubar)

if __name__=="__main__":
    global main_window, app
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    app = Pytures(main_window)
    app.mainloop()
```

I wrote it based in this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)

        main_window.title("Panel de pestañas en Tcl/Tk")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.greeting_frame = GreetingFrame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.greeting_frame, text="Saludos", padding=10)

        self.about_frame = AboutFrame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.about_frame, text="Acerca de", padding=10)

        self.notebook.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.pack()

        print(self.greeting_frame)
        type(self.greeting_frame)
        print(self.about_frame)
        type(self.about_frame)
        print(self.notebook)
        type(self.notebook)

class GreetingFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        print('Hola GreetingFrame')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.name_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.name_entry.pack()

        self.greet_button = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Saludar", command=self.say_hello)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.greet_label = ttk.Label(self)
        self.greet_label.pack()

    def say_hello(self):
        print(self.greet_button)
        self.greet_label["text"] = \
            "¡Hola, {}!".format(self.name_entry.get())

class AboutFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self)
        self.label["text"] = ("Visitanos en recursospython.com y "
                              "foro.recursospython.com.")
        self.label.pack()

        self.web_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visitar web")
        self.web_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.forum_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visitar foro")
        self.forum_button.pack()



if __name__=="__main__":
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(main_window)
    app.mainloop()
```

PD: I have choosen "exec()" despite being a newbie to create the new tabs because I think it is better to create only the tabs you need instead of creating a predetermined and limited number of hidden tabs that are raised when the user wants to create a new tab.

Comment: I don't understand this code, but one question: why do you not simply add tabs like this:  new_tab = ttk.Frame(notebook), notebook.add(new_tab)  ? You can use notebook.hide(tab) to hide a tab and notebook.forget(tab) to remove it from the notebook.

Comment: Feel free to ask what you don't understand. Because if I do what you say, how can I create a tab if I have no written the code? In that way I would have to populate a limited number of tabs and keep all hidden but one and, when the user wants to create a tab, I would have to make visible a hidden one.

Comment: No, why do you have to make visible a hidden one? That's the point where I dont understand you. Whatever it is your app is doing - why can't you create the tab and everything inside the tab at runtime, when the user clicks a button?

Comment: If I am sincere, I am "starting" with python, I only have a basic knowledgement. As I say in the example, I have based the code on the second one and every similar GUI I have found through the inthernet made the same thing when creating tabs, they declare in the code the tab Classes. That code shown is only a first approach, at this moment I have created two functions in the Pytures class that allows you to create and destroy tabs, clicking on File / New,  if it is what you mean.

Comment: As I want to place inside every tab a 3D plot and plot simple structures interactively, I thought I had to have objects and define those objects as classes, as the second example, in order to create the tabs and place things inside. As the user would like to assign an special name to a tab, I have no idea of any other way to achieve the same, but there could be a better and simpler way.

Comment: Now I understand you. I was misunderstanding the principle "all in Python is an object". I did the TabClassCreator method because I was thinking if I would create a unique class and referenciates all the tabs to that, the program would explode in some step as when you do `a=2` `b=a` `a+=1` and returns b=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have `pack()` geometry manager which center aligns the widget.

Use `grid()` geometry manager instead.

Change this statement <s>`self.pack()`</s> to `self.grid(row=0, column=0)`

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) but as before, it is my impression or it seems the tabs has no space to place things inside?

Comment: I have achieved more or less the same placing "self.notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")" after the if-else statement inside the function TabAttributeCreator and deleting "self.pack()" as you said.

Comment: @Pauner23 Yes, it is also possible with `pack()`. But you gain much more granularity with `grid()`.